# Can I use Cloudflare's Brotli along with GZIP Included in my .htaccess File?

Tags: wordpress, gzip, cloudflare, brotli

I would like to know if I could use Brotli compression provided by Cloudflare along with GZIP compression included in my .htaccess file? Would there be any reasons any one of you would not recommend doing that?

Best regards,

Tug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Brotli in combination with GZIP, however that does not mean it will use Brotli+GZIP... depending on situation and configuration of your server it will decide what to do. For example your server will deliver GZIP compressed output to Cloudflare... but cloudflare will detect that and just deliver that file to end user without any Brotli compression.. OR it will simply uncompress GZIP and do Brotli compression.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've read Brotli is better in certain ways but not by much, so I'll try and disable GZIP so Cloudflare can serve Brotli compression